# Obtaining the x / y frame coordinates of where a control ends

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am currently returning a `UITableViewCell*` which looks like this

```
Image --- Text ---  Button --- Image
```

The code that I am using looks like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {


        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; 

    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            //Add cell text

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.jpeg"];                      //Add cell image

    float f = [cell.textLabel alignmentRectInsets].right;



    UIButton *scanQRCodeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  //ADD UIButton

    scanQRCodeButton.frame = CGRectMake(?, ?, 50.0f, 50.0f);                     //Coordinates for image view

    [scanQRCodeButton setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:scanQRCodeButton];



    UIImageView *preArrowImage =[[UIImageView alloc]init ];                     //ADD Image View

    preArrowImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.jpeg"];

    preArrowImage.frame = CGRectMake(?, ?, 10, 30);                             //Coordinates for image view

    [cell.contentView addSubview:preArrowImage];



    return cell;
}
```

As mentioned before this is what the TableViewCell would look like

```
 ImageA --- Text ---  Button --- ImageB
```

I am aligning my button in the TableViewCell using the following

```
 scanQRCodeButton.frame = CGRectMake(?, ?, 50.0f, 50.0f);
```

and I am aligning the `UIImageView` using the following

```
 preArrowImage.frame = CGRectMake(?, ?, 10, 30);
```

Now my question is that in reality I am using hard coded variables instead of `?` . How can I find out the x frame coordinate of where the Text ends so I could utilize that value instead of hard-coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there are some issues with your code. You are adding subviews to the cell's `contentView` every time the cell is reused. That code should instead be in the `if (cell == nil)` body so that it only happens once. You will of course then need a reference to those subviews which you could do by either using a `UITableViewCell` subclass with dedicated variables or by setting tags.

Next up, generally speaking you can do something like:

```
CGFloat labelRightEdge = CGRectGetMaxX(textLabel.frame);
```

I'm not sure it will work in this case and cause you problems when you are trying to align things with `UITableViewCell` built in views. Those views are laid out internally and aren't really meant to be used in conjunction with custom subviews. I would instead recommend building all of the views yourself by making a `UITableViewCell` subclass and then you can lay out all the views as you see fit in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Could you also explain why it is necessary to check if (cell == nil) . When exactly does the method `tableView` get called ? Would it get called multiple times for the same cell ?

Comment: You should read the documentation for `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`. Check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7 In general, cells will get reused when you scroll so that new ones don't keep getting created, but instead only if there are no reusable cells available.